# How to make multiple inline-block elems to stretch full width of the container?

Tags: html, block, css

What is the best way to implement input field and button behavior as displayed here: 
[image]

Comment: Button and input field together must take all the width container proivde. Button must take width according its internal structure (simple inline-block). Input field must take ALL OTHER SPACE. When the container resizes button width must still the same, input width must change accordingly. Input and button must always be on the same line (nowrap).

Comment: Is the width of your container fixed? If so, it's easy. If not...you could try setting display:block on the input element, and floating the button to the right.

Comment: @RyanBallantyne input with display:block does not stretch. http://jsfiddle.net/xuWXz/14/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I like the answer of ScottS, but just to have an alternative: you could use table-like behaviour in CSS:

**CSS**

```
.formline{
    display: table;
}
.txt{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
input[type=text]{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class=formline>
    <div class=txt>
        <input type=text>
    </div>
    <input type=submit value=submit>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/VaFSP/

Answer (score 13):

Yes, with some html and css in place that [uses some magic](http://web.archive.org/web/20150618153020/http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/?) between `float` and `overflow: hidden`, you [can see it working in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrHGD/8/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div>Some Text</div>
    <form>
        <button>MyButton</button>
        <div class="stretcher"><input type="text" /></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.stretcher {
    overflow: hidden;
}

button {
    float: right;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Nice and compact, better than my solution which fakes table-behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/VaFSP/. You might add "box-sizing: border-box;" for the input field.

Comment: @WillemVanBockstal--yeah, I wasn't going for "pretty" in the example. In Firefox the button is quite a bit larger in height than the input, and I imagine the OP may want to add a `white-space: nowrap` on the `form` or some other wrapper to insure the `button` and `input` remain on the same line. I figured the OP can play with those matters, I gave him the core idea of a direction to go.

Comment: I like the both solutions. I knew about display: table-cell etc, but  overflow: hidden thing is something new to me. But the both solutions work in ie7+. Is it possible to do it somewhow in ie6? Is an extra table markup inescapable?