# How do I make an inline-block stretch?

Tags: html, css

I want the image to be left aligned but the text-block to be center aligned in the remaining space. How do I do that?

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://mobile-streetmaps.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/itunesArtwork-1-08-18-08.gif" />
        <center>
            <div>
                <h1>Hello</h1>
                <p>I R Awesome</p>
            </div>
        </center>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

`img {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
center {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:orange;
}`

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PVgT6/

Comment: Something like this.. http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/PVgT6/14/

Comment: more like: http://jsfiddle.net/PVgT6/15/ (i hacked it by guessing the remaining width to be 80%, it may be different for your screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [Willem Van Bockstal answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402647/how-to-make-multiple-inline-block-elems-to-stretch-full-width-of-the-container) to a similar problem, you could use table-like behaviour in CSS.

First Give the list element a class and then make it a table in the css.

```
<li class="imgtext">

.imgtext {
    display: table;
 }
```

Then you make the center display: table-cell.

```
center {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:orange;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PVgT6/16/)

Comment: This is great! So the real answer is: use a table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a percentage based solution.

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3T3g/2/)

First, we give our lists a class to tell them how to handle their contents.

```
<li class="list-image">...</li>
```

Then we give our image a width, and make it play nice with the div:

```
li.list-image img {
    width: 20%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Our div needs to have `100% - (image-width * 2)` for its width.  This allows it to be centered in the `ul`.  If you just want it centered in the div, (which will be slightly to the right side), you can do `100% - image-width`, e.g., `80%`.

```
li.list-image > div {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: thats kind of like my hack solution, but a bit better. still though, i would rather a solution that doesnt resize my image based on the size of the screen. i am using a liquid layout so I cannot realistically go with a solution like this.

Comment: Liquid layout means that its relative to the size of the screen.  I don't understand.  Could you clarify?

Comment: this entire list is inside another div which is defined to be 66% of its parents width

Comment: Okay, so what's wrong [with this](http://jsfiddle.net/v3T3g/3/embedded/result/).  I'd be happy to edit my answer :-)

Comment: resize the window, see how the size of the picture changes? thats bad

Comment: If you want to mix pixels and percents, you're going to need JavaScript.  If your icon is 40px<sup>2</sup>, then on an iPhone, the div with the text will have 220px of space, and on a 1080p monitor, it'll have 1240px of space.  So you can get kinda-centered text with CSS at `81%`, but it's be off by hundreds of pixels on a monitor.  Maybe a wrapper might work (a div around the img), but it still won't be perfectly centered.